# Any way to get more info from unhandled exceptions caught by Application_Error in Global.asax?

Tags: asp.net, global-asax, unhandled-exception, application-error

In production, I have the Application_Error event handled in Global.asax to log (and email me) details of any uncaught exceptions that sneak through:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) // code simplified a bit for SO
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    MyTools.LogError("Global.asax::Application_Error", "An unhandled exception occurred", ex);
}
```

The error messages themselves, however are usually useless; there is a stack trace, but with **no line numbers** and **often no reference to any of my own code**, only .net framework (BCL) methods. Sometimes there is a hint as to the **page name** at least, but that's about as good as it gets.

Example:

> Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
>
> The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80072746.
>
> System.Web
>
> Boolean HandleError(System.Exception)
>
> at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>      at ASP.**aRealPageName_aspx**.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

So any idea how I can **get global.asax to give me more useful error info?**

I know I could put a try-catch into the code if there was a way to tell where to put it, but there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

If your production server doesn't have pdb files it will not give you line numbers.
Copy your pdb files along with your dlls to get more info.

Comment: Oh! Hadn't thought of this. Will it work even though I'm not running in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, as long as you have pdb files generated with your build (which is the default)